# How to collect specific terms in an equation and set them to new parameters?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I have this equation

```
FullSimplify[Eins[[1, 1]]]

(1/3)*((9*Derivative[1, 0][a][t, y]^2)/a[t, y]^2 + 
   n*(6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 0, 0, 4][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 2, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 0, 4, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, 
        r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      2*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
           Derivative[0, 2, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
      2*Derivative[0, 4, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]) + 
      (1/a[t, y])*(n* Derivative[1, 0][a][t,y]*(-6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
              6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
        18*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][\[CapitalPsi]][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
        Derivative[1, 0, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + 
              Derivative[1, 0, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
        Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]])))
```

Or:
[image]

How to tell MA to collect $S^{(0, 0, 0, 2)}$ + $S^{(0, 0, 2, 0)}$ + $S^{(0, 2,0, 0)}$ and call them with a new variable say Div-S? ( I think later one can set Div-S to $\partial_i^2 S$ in Tex format)

Also in the same time I want to collect $\Psi$ as S terms, I.e., to collect $\Psi^{(0, 0, 0, 2)}$ + $\Psi^{(0, 0, 2, 0)}$ + $\Psi^{(0, 2,0, 0)}$ terms (because the sum equals $\partial_i^2 \Psi$ ) and set them to say :Div-psi

Finally, Xi terms: to collect:

- $Xi^{(0, 0, 0, 4)}$ + $Xi^{(0, 0, 4, 0)}$ + $Xi^{(0, 4,0, 0)}$
- $Xi^{(0, 0, 2, 2)}$ + $Xi^{(0, 2, 0, 2)}$ + $Xi^{(0, 2, 2, 0)}$
- $Xi^{(1, 0, 0, 2)}$ - $ Xi^{(1, 2, 0, 0)}$ + $Xi^{(1, 0, 2, 0)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

e1 = (1/3)*((9*Derivative[1, 0][a][t, y]^2)/a[t, y]^2 + 
     n*(6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        Derivative[0, 0, 0, 4][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        Derivative[0, 0, 2, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        Derivative[0, 0, 4, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        2*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        Derivative[0, 2, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
        2*Derivative[0, 4, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ]) + (1/
        a[t, y])*(n*Derivative[1, 0][a][t, y]*
          (-6*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] - 
          6*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] - 
          6*Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] - 
          18*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
          Derivative[1, 0, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] + 
          Derivative[1, 0, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] - 
          Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ])));
```

Replacement rules:

```
repl = {Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] :> DivS -
     Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] -
     Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ],
   Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] :> 
    DivΨ -
     Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ] -
     Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][Ψ][t, r, θ, ϕ],
   Derivative[0, 0, 0, 4][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] :> Xi4 -
     Derivative[0, 0, 4, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] -
     Derivative[0, 4, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ],
   Derivative[0, 0, 2, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] :> Xi2 -
     Derivative[0, 2, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] -
     Derivative[0, 2, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ],
   Derivative[1, 0, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] :> Xi12 -
     Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ] -
     Derivative[1, 0, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, θ, ϕ]};

e2 = e1 /. repl // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Hello@BobHanlon, thanks for your answer. But I think there is a problem in the output. Only the first replacement done probably: `Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
  Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] :> DivS`  , But for instance, the code doesn't replace `Derivative[1, 0, 0, 2][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + Derivative[1, 0, 2, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - 
  Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] -> Xi12`, because  `Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][Xi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] ` still there.

Comment: I mean in all the second replacements , it did not replace for example `x+y+z-> Xi12`, but it substitutes by `x= Xi12-2y`,

Comment: Hay @BobHanlon. By the way, I’d like to say that your answer is great! Cause a small detail in the rules differes.I mean if the rule `Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] + Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ]+ Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][S][t, r, θ, ϕ] : > DivS ` the replacement doesn't work. Only the way you write rules works. I don't why? But that's amazing detail in the solution! :) thanks again